# Styling individual bullets in a <ul> where bullets are displayed inline

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have styled an unordered list for a responsive layout so that at full width the bullets display inline with '/' after each one, and at lower width the '/' suffix disappears and the bullets display in a vertical list.

So, at full width it reads:

> bullet 1 / bullet 2 / bullet 3 / bullet 4 /

at lower width:

> bullet 1
> bullet 2
> bullet 3
> bullet 4

The CSS for adding the '/' after each bullet is as follows:

```
.info li:after {content: " /";}
```

And the html for the list:

```
<div class="info">
    <ul>
    <li >bullet 1</a>
    </li>  ... and so on
```

I would like to remove the '/' from the **final bullet only**, so it displays thus:

> bullet 1 / bullet 2 / bullet 3 / bullet 4

I have tried to add an ID to the final bullet with these two methods, but neither have worked:

```
#noStroke {content: "";} 
#noStroke li:after {content: "";}
```

Can anyone advise on how to remove the '/' from the final bullet?

NOTE: just typing the / after each bullet doesn't work, as I don't want them to display on lower resolutions!

Comment: try something with `:last-child` [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the following:

Did you put the `id` on the `li` element? In that case try

```
.info li#noStroke:after {content: none;}
```

Alternatively, you do not need to use an `id` for the last element, you can just use:

```
.info li:last-child:after {content: none;}
```

Beware of really old IE browsers (7 and lower) which may not support `:last-child`.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:last-child` pseudo-class selector.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo

```css
.info li:after {
  content: " /";
}
.info li:last-child:after {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <ul>
    <li>bullet 1</li>
    <li>bullet 2</li>
    <li>bullet 3</li>
    <li>bullet 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro but the one above worked perfectly!